# Spring SAML 2.0 extention does not use the public certificate imported in the keystore.jks

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am new to saml 2.0. I'm trying to understand the saml 2.0 springboot extension. I came across the sample app by Vincenzo De Notaris and Thomas Darimont.

Here is the git hub sample: https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample

In saml security config, the keymanager bean needs to be defined. Because saml extension uses a private key to sign and a public certificate to verify. Correct me if I'm wrong.

here is the bean definition.

```
@Bean
public KeyManager keyManager() {
    DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource storeFile = loader
            .getResource("classpath:/saml/samlKeystore.jks");
    String storePass = "nalle123";
    Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<>();
    passwords.put("apollo", "nalle123");
    String defaultKey = "apollo";
    return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
}
```

here **samlKeystore.jks** has an expired private key with alias **'apollo'**.

There are two more public certificates with alias **'ssocircle'** and **'startcom'**.

When I run the application, I saw that only the private key is used for signing the message. I could not see where the certificate ssocircle is used. I'm able to see the ssocircle login page and able to log in.

I deleted this certificate from the Keystore, and I tried to log in again, I'm still getting the login page and I am able to successfully log in.

It is the same with keycloak as well. The samlKeystore.jks needs to be imported into the keys section of the client. I don't seem to understand the need for the public certificate.

**To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior.**

checkout the code from https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample.
in the resources/saml folder delete the ssocircle certificate from samlKeystore.jks, build the project, and run the spring-boot application.
When third-party login is clicked, it successfully lands on the login page and allows you to log in.

Expected behavior
It should not allow you to log in without a valid certificate.

I want to understand the role of the public certificate. how does it work in a production environment

here is the link to keycloak implementation:
https://blog.codecentric.de/secure-spring-boot-app-saml-keycloak

```
D:\learning\spring-boot-security-saml-sample-master\src\main\resources\saml>keytool -v -list -keystore samlKeystore.jks
Enter keystore password:
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: apollo
Creation date: Feb 22, 2023
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=com:vdenotaris:spring:sp
Issuer: CN=com:vdenotaris:spring:sp
Serial number: 18677e23aa8
Valid from: Wed Feb 22 12:17:40 IST 2023 until: Tue Feb 22 12:19:20 IST 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  0B:1A:D2:81:D3:C6:4E:FC:09:48:33:F9:A9:F8:1F:37
     SHA1: 26:71:0D:7A:23:F1:95:66:4D:FE:20:DD:3D:C9:21:E4:2A:B9:BA:91
     SHA256: 9A:63:5B:70:BE:B5:0E:4C:A0:2F:20:44:93:60:59:F7:07:8D:20:01:C3:06:18:2C:79:0C:A3:72:6E:D5:02:02
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 1


*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: demo
Creation date: Feb 22, 2023
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=demo
Issuer: CN=demo
Serial number: 18677b08857
Valid from: Wed Feb 22 11:23:23 IST 2023 until: Tue Feb 22 11:25:03 IST 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  13:24:00:F4:DF:D7:EF:4E:E4:E9:03:E9:AC:AB:15:48
     SHA1: 9D:73:33:43:93:27:6F:CE:D9:A9:3E:50:E8:46:43:92:9C:5A:58:44
     SHA256: 89:01:FB:46:9B:0F:F7:12:86:F0:7C:F4:C9:D9:F7:A4:A8:FE:00:53:20:AD:18:03:E9:A0:10:53:66:97:42:AE
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 1


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

only these entries are present in the keystore.

I looked into the SAML responses. I see there is a public certificate.

but I don't see where it is being used.

below is my saml repsponse

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="s2d972ea2347e60347a1f50d8bf682a1279b037cfb" InResponseTo="a3afi5c0b1h80j6idf6j56abejf6jf" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2023-03-06T06:40:00Z" Destination="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO">
 <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer>
 <samlp:Status xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <samlp:StatusCode xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"></samlp:StatusCode>
 </samlp:Status>
 <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="s28dd7e555bd25f51c926afb191d60ac2c39189a01" IssueInstant="2023-03-06T06:40:00Z" Version="2.0">
  <saml:Issuer>https://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></ds:SignatureMethod>
    <ds:Reference URI="#s28dd7e555bd25f51c926afb191d60ac2c39189a01">
     <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></ds:Transform>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></ds:Transform>
     </ds:Transforms>
     <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></ds:DigestMethod>
     <ds:DigestValue>s+Ad/+XlvVbqHvoRWIfn1nH07k0=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
   </ds:SignedInfo>
   <ds:SignatureValue>
DGZLc3YyWwRU1khFvXlTTTtUPOaPNFUhjTcHGehrPb6b24w/aduB+upSfqqqsam7D4RAanSv+MlS
MPyXoyXpHIxRytNJri6nlagR3hRPvxKEqTbju52CEIhLOw/T8HTjL6ZjlMMLd79Aef8Z7+ew684q
LtCkq0KzUq8lIjQ+bdhe4WoW3EDRh9kH+09Y3w2e0MoNg/I4ljdLqR2THZpcZciGwi4lN6vBBNg8
KQKbCMsKB9HHkAloWMbGMKS4AvfhFHv17eaLEohJacuZiUrdQbTcW1ay+iWmWWTYKeMO0GGjRA2y
sQ8Khx0UHJr3EjvmXo+cCmD7oKQPZbxT3uI9Fg==
</ds:SignatureValue>
   <ds:KeyInfo>
    <ds:X509Data>
     <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
   </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <saml:Subject>
   <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" NameQualifier="https://idp.ssocircle.com">manjosh.1990@yahoo.com</saml:NameID>
   <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
    <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a3afi5c0b1h80j6idf6j56abejf6jf" NotOnOrAfter="2023-03-06T06:50:00Z" Recipient="http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO"></saml:SubjectConfirmationData>
   </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
  </saml:Subject>
  <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2023-03-06T06:30:00Z" NotOnOrAfter="2023-03-06T06:50:00Z">
   <saml:AudienceRestriction>
    <saml:Audience>com:vdenotaris:spring:sp</saml:Audience>
   </saml:AudienceRestriction>
  </saml:Conditions>
  <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2023-03-06T06:39:52Z" SessionIndex="s2bfad16a66fb7f8b82c0386b459e368a8ce5c1501">
   <saml:AuthnContext>
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
   </saml:AuthnContext>
  </saml:AuthnStatement>
  <saml:AttributeStatement>
   <saml:Attribute Name="EmailAddress">
    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">manjosh.1990@yahoo.com</saml:AttributeValue>
   </saml:Attribute>
   <saml:Attribute Name="UserID">
    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">manjosh</saml:AttributeValue>
   </saml:Attribute>
   <saml:Attribute Name="FirstName">
    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">manjosh</saml:AttributeValue>
   </saml:Attribute>
   <saml:Attribute Name="LastName">
    <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">r</saml:AttributeValue>
   </saml:Attribute>
  </saml:AttributeStatement>
 </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

I tried to look into the public certificate

[image]
this is what is present in the SAML response.

Now Im wondering how its allowing to login when i dont have this certificate in my keystore.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you are asking the right question, though perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Key rotation is a fundamental part of security. This is why Spring Security is built to house more than one key in `RelyingPartyRegistration`, for example. In this way, the new upcoming key can be added in and there can be a buffer period before the old key is rotated out. 

Whether you use symmetric or asymmetric keys, they will expire and you will need to rotate.

Comment: I have updated my question. my question is regarding the use of public certificates in saml 2.0 extension. in the sample app, it works even without the certificate. where exactly is it used? I want to know if I have missed a configuration. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate of the identity provider (in your case SSOCircle) is used when SAML Spring extension receivs the SAML SSO response from the IDP. The SAML response or the assertion itself is signed by the IDP with the IDP's private key. The certificate holds the public key and can be used to validate the signature.

The redirect to the login page of the IDP happens without involvement of the IDP certificate. The login at the IDP is off scope for SAML. You need to have an eye on the response which is sent as POST request back to the SPRING SAML extension.

Comment: In my keystore I don't have this certificate. I see the SSO circle certificate in the SAML response. Why is the login allowed even without the public certificate in samlKeystore.jks? I have updated my question with my findings.