# spring security 6: saml integration: redirection, registrationId

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

As I want to update my app to spring boot 3 and implementing the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter does not work anymore, I try now to use the official spring boot security for my saml integration. I am inside a company network, I have the xml file at hand. The old implementation works fine and allows me sso, so everything is configured properly. But I could need some help with spring security now.

From some examples I found searching the net I tried this code

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration{

@Value("${saml.idpURL}")
private String idpMetadata;

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain app (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

    http.authorizeHttpRequests ((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()

)
.saml2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
return http.build();
}


@Bean
RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository() {

     RelyingPartyRegistration relyingPartyRegistration =   
RelyingPartyRegistrations.fromMetadataLocation(idpMetadata)
registrationId("myAppname").build();
  return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistration);

 }
}
```

(Edit: error from original question disappeared after adding a registrationID)

After adding a registrationId I succeeded in reaching my IDP (yeah!).
But it tells me to f*** off.
Now I am not sure on why my login-attempt is rejected. The xml-file is the same. 1. What exactly is the registration ID supposed to bear?
2. How does the "DefaultRedirectStrategy" operate?

My app is running on http://localhost:8080/"myAppname">
With the old implementation I am exactly there after having succesfully authenticated. VaadinUI has a langding page, route=""

The implementation now says
023-03-16 15:56:32.743 DEBUG 18856 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache : Saved request http://localhost:8080/"myAppName"/ to session

2023-03-16 15:56:32.743 DEBUG 18856 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/"myAppName"/saml2/authenticate/"registrationId"

2023-03-16 15:56:32.743 DEBUG 18856 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request

2023-03-16 15:56:32.754 DEBUG 18856 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy : Securing GET /saml2/authenticate/"myAppName"

2023-03-16 15:56:32.754 DEBUG 18856 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext

2023-03-16 15:56:32.756 DEBUG 18856 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] aml2AuthenticationRequestContextResolver : Creating SAML 2.0 Authentication Request for Asserting Party ["registrationId"]

So, please anybody help. In the "old" implementation the was a somehow not used keystore available (like here: [Spring SAML 2.0 extention does not use the public certificate imported in the keystore.jks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75427866/spring-saml-2-0-extention-does-not-use-the-public-certificate-imported-in-the-ke) ) so I do not think that I have to send actual credentials as at my IDP the "myAppName" is set. As far as I understand, everybody using this link can authenticate, but has different roles (r, r/w, like that).
So: I think it has something to do with the registrationId or the redirecting stuff. How can I change it to the way it worked before? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I think I found the problem: the request to http://localhost:8080/myAppname goes out as http://localhost:8080/myAppname/saml/authetication/registrationId which is not known on the server side. Unfortunately the added part /saml/authentication/registrationId is hardcoded in spring security. I don't know if and if yes how to change this. Anybody on this planet can answer yes or no?

Edit : now I finally have a log from the F5. "It reads: Error: No SP Connector attached to sso matching authentication request. ... Issuer from the authentication request must match entity_id from DP Connector"

Pleeeeeeeeeeease somebody tell me what the sp connector is in the spring security saml.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by analysing the old requests and adding exactly the values for entityId and assertionConsumerServieLocation as before to the new implementation. Still don't know what the registrationId is good for, but anyway. So now I have the next problem and will open new question.